# call a function from another file and get a random result for each call

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, random, call

I have a random.js file containing this to get random fake ip

```
exports.ip = function () {
    let random = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0); 
    return random
}
```

and I call the variable in the send.js file to replace string {randomip}

```
let replace_tag = function (to) {

    config.message.subject = config.message.subject
        .replace("{randomip}", random.ip)
        .replace("{email}", to)
        .replace("{date}", random.date);

    config.message.fromname = config.message.fromname
        .replace("{randomip}", random.ip)
        .replace("{email}", to)
        .replace("{date}", random.date);

    config.message.fromemail = config.message.fromemail
        .replace("{randomip}", random.ip)
        .replace("{email}", to)
        .replace("{date}", random.date);

}
```

but it will only produce one generated ip, I want to make it generate random every time it is called will produce different values

I have tried inserting it in the loop but still not working

I call the replace function in another function then enter it into loop like that

```
let kirim = function (to) {

    replace_tag(to);

    let message = {
        from: config.message.fromname+'<'+config.message.fromemail+'>',
        to: to,
        subject: config.message.subject,
        text: config.message.text,
        html: html
    };

    transporter.sendMail(message, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
             return console.log(error.response)
        }
        console.log('Message sent: ',info.accepted);
    });
};


(async () => {

    for (var i in list) {

        kirim(list[i]);
        await delay(config.send.delay*1000); 

    }

})();
```

Comment: you can export a function instead

Comment: You exported a value not a function that generates a value

Comment: I've edited it to be a function but it's still not random every call

Comment: are you calling it as `random.ip()` and not `random.ip`

Comment: I call random.ip because I import it as an object

Comment: Are you saying that you get the same result for subject, fromname and fromemail? That's hard to believe

Comment: check post I have added another code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I call the replace function in another function then enter it into loop

Ah, there's your problem. Your `replace_tag` function will change the `config` object, and after the first call it doesn't contain the template tag any more but the replacement result. Further calls to `replace_tag` won't find `{randomip}` in your configuration any more, so no new ips are generated.

You should instead keep the configuration constant (immutable), and create new message objects every time you need one. Each of those objects will then have different randomised IP addresses.

```
// takes a string, returns a new string
function replace_tags(input, email) {
    return input
    .replace("{randomip}", random.ip)
    .replace("{email}", email)
    .replace("{date}", random.date);
}
// returns a new object, leaves config.message unaltered
function get_customised_message_template(to) {
    return {
        subject: replace_tags(config.message.subject, to),
        fromname: replace_tags(config.message.fromname, to),
        fromemail: replace_tags(config.message.fromemail, to),
    };
}

function kirim(to) {
    const random_message = get_customised_message_template(to);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const message = {
        from: random_message.fromname+'<'+random_message.fromemail+'>',
        to: to,
        subject: random_message.subject,
        text: config.message.text,
        html: html
    };

    transporter.sendMail(message, (error, info) => {
        if (error) console.log(error.response);
        else console.log('Message sent: ', info.accepted);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's will work.

random.js:

```
exports.ip = function() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 
        0)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0);
}
```

send.js:

```
let replace_tag = function (to) {

    config.message.subject = config.message.subject
        .replace("{randomip}", random.ip())
        .replace("{email}", to)
        .replace("{date}", random.date);

    config.message.fromname = config.message.fromname
        .replace("{randomip}", random.ip())
        .replace("{email}", to)
        .replace("{date}", random.date);

    config.message.fromemail = config.message.fromemail
        .replace("{randomip}", random.ip())
        .replace("{email}", to)
        .replace("{date}", random.date);

}
```

Comment: Try to create a function that generate random ip, for example:
function getRandomIp() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 
        0)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0);
}

and call it where you want to generate random ip

Comment: yes it's the same as my function but when I export it to another file it can't be random

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRandomIp() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 
    0)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0)+"."+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 0);
}
let replace_tag = function (to) {

    config.message.subject = config.message.subject
        .replace("{randomip}", getRandomIp())
        .replace("{email}", to)
        .replace("{date}", random.date);

    config.message.fromname = config.message.fromname
        .replace("{randomip}", getRandomIp())
        .replace("{email}", to)
        .replace("{date}", random.date);

    config.message.fromemail = config.message.fromemail
        .replace("{randomip}", getRandomIp())
        .replace("{email}", to)
        .replace("{date}", random.date);

}
```

Comment: what if I export the function to another file and call it like an object

Comment: I think you can

Comment: How you linked your files?

Comment: using const random = require('./random.js');